# Working Out The Time Difference Between Two Rows On Multiple Occurances

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, datediff, self-join

I'm working on what will be a new function but I'm trying to get a foundation of how to work out the time difference between two rows every time a value appears in two other columns appear (prev_value, current_value). The difference will then be wrapped in a sum for a final value against each ID.

The example below is a small portion of the table, so if we use ID 194422 hopefully I can get my point across.

The Datediff I'm trying to work out would be between every record that has a Current_Value 12026 and Prev_Value 12026. So between the top 2 rows, I would expect 3 minute difference and between rows 3 and 4 , I would expect a 4 minute difference.

If the row contains a current_value and prev_value of 12026 then I would also include this in the time so on row 13,14,15 I would expect a 9 min difference between row 13 and 15.

I would then group and sum these results by the ID.

```
ROWID|  ID   | Columnname | prev_value |     current_value  |      OperationTime


1    |197684 |  STATUSID  |    1       |     12026          |     2020-02-11 13:37:00.0010
2    |197684 |  STATUSID  | 12026      |       1            |     2020-02-11 13:40:00.000
3    |197684 |  STATUSID  |    1       |     12026          |     2020-02-11 13:44:00.000
4    |197684 |  STATUSID  | 12026      |       1            |     2020-02-11 13:48:00.000
5    |198662 |  STATUSID  |    1       |     12026          |     2020-02-24 15:10:00.000
6    |198662 |  STATUSID  | 12026      |       1            |     2020-02-24 15:20:00.000
7    |198662 |  STATUSID  |    1       |     12026          |     2020-02-24 15:23:00.000
8    |198662 |  STATUSID  | 12026      |       1            |     2020-02-24 15:41:00.000
9    |198662 |  STATUSID  |    1       |     12026          |     2020-02-24 16:24:00.000
10   |198662 |  STATUSID  | 12026      |       1            |     2020-02-24 17:05:00.000
11   |194422 |  STATUSID  |    1       |     12026          |     2020-02-25 09:04:00.000
12   |194422 |  STATUSID  | 12026      |       8            |     2020-02-25 09:07:00.000
13   |198662 |  STATUSID  |    1       |     12026          |     2020-02-26 15:32:00.000
14   |198662 |  STATUSID  | 12026      |     12026          |     2020-02-26 15:40:00.000
15   |198662 |  STATUSID  | 12026      |       1            |     2020-02-26 15:41:00.000
16   |194422 |  STATUSID  |    1       |     12026          |     2020-03-02 16:06:00.000
17   |194422 |  STATUSID  | 12026      |       8            |     2020-03-02 16:15:00.000
```

At the end result would then be:

```
      RowID |  TimeSpent(Mins)

    194422  |     9
    197684  |     7
    198662  |     78
```

I've now tried a few different methods but records are either missing or incorrect times are being retrieved.

I've look at a CTE with an INNER and LEFT JOIN and OUTER JOIN back on the CTE, I've tried two CTE's, I've looked at LAG, RANK and ROW_NUMBER() in all examples.

The script below sort of works but it doesn't pull in all my results and in this example it misses ID 194422.

```
DECLARE @STATUSID INT 
SET @STATUSID = 12026 

;WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT prev_value, 
                current_value, 
                OPERATIONTIME,
                ROWID,
                ID,
            DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY prev_value ORDER BY operationtime) AS ROWNUMBER  
         FROM   AUDITREVIEW
         WHERE  columnname = 'STATUSID' 
                AND ( current_value = @STATUSID 
                       OR prev_value = @STATUSID )    
                ) 

SELECT *,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE,  CTE2.cte2OPERATIONTIME, CTE1.operationtime) as t
    INTO #Temp
FROM 
    CTE AS CTE1
OUTER APPLY 
        (SELECT  top 1
           prev_value as cte2prev_value, 
                current_value cte2current_value, 
                OPERATIONTIME cte2OPERATIONTIME,
                ROWID cte2rowID,
                ID cte2ID,
                DENSE_RANK () OVER ( ORDER BY operationtime) AS cte2ROWNUMBER 
            FROM CTE 
            WHERE CTE.ID = CTE1.ID 
            AND CTE.PREV_VALUE = CTE1.CURRENT_VALUE
            AND CTE.ROWNUMBER < CTE1.ROWNUMBER
            ORDER BY CTE.OPERATIONTIME DESC
            ) CTE2

--WHERE CTE1.WORKORDERID = 194422


SELECT SUM(t), ID
FROM #Temp
WHERE cte2prev_value <> @STATUSID
GROUP BY ID

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Comment: I think the last record should be 
17   |194422 |  STATUSID  | 12026      |       1           |     2020-03-02 16:15:00.000

instead of 
17   |194422 |  STATUSID  | 12026      |       8            |     2020-03-02 16:15:00.000

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
SELECT a1.ID, 
       SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a1.OperationTime, a2.OperationTime)) Time_Spent_in_Minutes
FROM AUDITREVIEW a1
     JOIN AUDITREVIEW a2 ON a2.ID = a1.ID
                            AND ((a1.ROWID = a2.ROWID)
                                 OR (a1.ROWID + 1 = a2.ROWID))
WHERE(a1.current_value = 12026 AND a2.prev_value = 12026)
     AND ((a1.prev_value = 1 AND a2.current_value = 1)
          OR (a1.current_value = 12026 AND a1.prev_value = 12026)
          OR (a2.current_value = 12026 AND a2.prev_value = 12026))
GROUP BY a1.ID
ORDER BY 1;
```

[**db<>fiddle demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4d271322e557c62f9d928a2d88da9976)

Comment: Hi Sacse, thank you for your answer, the script doesn't seem to be pulling through any results using your suggestion.

Comment: did you also check the results in db<>fiddle example (I have provided the link to that in the answer)?